# Display Image using <img> tag and JSP scriptlet?

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets, jsp-tags

I am trying to display the image on **JSP** page using Following code

```
<% String url;
        url=config.getServletContext().getRealPath("/images/1.jpg"); %>
        <img src= <%=url%>/>
```

I also try to give double-quot but it does not work can anyone tell me can i give absolute path to the image file like this or i have to use the **streams** for it ?

And which is the best way to store images and uploaded file relative path or absolute path or into the database ?

Comment: Please do confirm that you are learning Java EE from the current version of whatever resources, or book you are referring to. You should not use `Scriplets` anymore. Use JSTL, and EL instead. Check the [JSTL](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info), and [EL](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info) tag wiki for more details about them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display the image within the html you must give a relative path to the root of the webpage.